# Understanding WCF ServiceBehaviorProperty ConcurrencyMode

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I would like to understand the `ServiceBehavior.ConcurrencyMode` property.

Consider the following code on service side:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMySercice {
   [OperationContract]
   int mycall(int a);
}
/*** HERE I WILL GENERATE Two variants of this code ***/
[ServiceBehaviour(InstanceContext = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService {
   // Constructors...
   // implementations of interface
   public int mycall(int a) { ... }
}
class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      MyServiceMyS = new MyService(...); /* Creating service instance */
      Uri MyUri = new Uri("http://services.mycompany.com/services/"); /* Base address for my hosted service */
      using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(MyS)) { /* Defining service host, configuration file contains info regarding endpoints, not shown here for clarity */
         host.Start();
         host.Stop();
      }
   }
}
```

Now consider that I would like to call this service, please consider 10 machines in the web that may call my service.
At a certain point, it happens that these 10 machines ALL MAKE 10 simultaneous requests for `int mycall(int a)`.
I would like to examine these scenarios:

SCENARIO 1

```
...
/*** VARIANT 1 ***/
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContext = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService {
   ...
}
...
```

SCENARIO 2

```
...
/*** VARIANT 2 ***/
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContext = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService {
   ...
}
...
```

So, 10 simultaneous calls arrive... what does it happen in both cases? Please tell me whether I am right or wrong:

In Scenario 1, single threaded, these 10 calls are queued and executed one at a time. My service (THE SAME INSTANCE OF MY SERVICE)'s method will be called ten times in sequence. In Scenario 2, multiple threaded, WCF will cause 10 threads to simultaneously call my service method.

Is it true what I said? 
Thanks

Comment: In both scenarios, your code will not compile because `ServiceHost` has neither a `Start()` nor a `Stop()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both scenarios all 10 clients will be served in parallel by 10 different threads. The reason is that `ConcurrencyMode` setting is dependent on `InstanceContextMode` setting. `InstanceContextMode` defines how WCF engine servers client requests - how is new instance of the service created if request arrives:

- `PerCall` - each request is served by a new instance of the service
- `PerSession` - all request from single proxy instance are served by the same service instance
- `Single` - per host singleton - all request are served by the same instance of the service

So your description will be correct if you also use `InstanceContextMode.Single` but default value is `PerCall` for bindings not supporting sessions (basicHttpBinding, webHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding without security context or reliable session) or `PerSession` for bindings supporting sessions (netTcpBinding, netNamedPipeBinding, wsHttpBinding in default configuration using security context).

`ConcurrencyMode` defines how can an instance of the service be used if multiple requests want to access it. For example `PerCall` instancing with `Multiple` concurrency is the same as `Single` concurrency because each instance is used to serve exactly one request regardless the concurrency setting.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav, I edited the code specifying Singel as InstanceCOntextMode, I am very sorry for not doing this before... I guess now my description is correct right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes if you have singleton service your description should be right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `InstanceContextMode.Single` what you've described should be the behavior you should see. Beyond 10 simultaneous calls, you would actually still get the same behavior, because you would hit the default throttling limit of 10 for `MaxConcurrentSessions` on your service's `ServiceThrottlingBehavior` (a "session" as far as the throttling behavior is concerned is the total number of channels that can be open at a time).